# Load textures from images stored in StreamingDataPath

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I'm trying very hard to understand how should i store and load some images in my Unity app for Android platform.

From what i understood, i should store them in the Application.streamingAssetsPath.
However i don't know how to access them.

Note: My images are in sub-folders within the streaming assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here a some pages that I think might help you:

The docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

Others:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/210909/android-streamingassets-file-access.html

https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-loading-image-from-streamingassets.717869/

Personally, I do not develop on android so I can’t help you more unfortunately but I am hopping this can help a bit.

Comment: - The first link is the Unity docs but for some reasons, they redirect this problem to the UnityWebRequest.GetTexture and on this same page it's said that this function is obsolete.
- The second link is just too old, this is obsolete too.
- The third is the right solution for a non android app. This method work in Unity editor but as soon as you try to build, it is impossible to reach the images in the streaming assets

Thank anyway.

Comment: Here's the Unity solution: "UnityWebRequest.GetTexture is obsolete. Use UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture instead."
They really should update that page.